# Getting the minimum value and maximum value out of a series of numbers in C# without sorting

Tags: c#, loops, if-statement

The goal is to make a program that when a series of numbers is entered, the minimum and maximum are displayed.  -99 will be used as a sentinel.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication12
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double number = 0, maxValue = 0, minValue = 0;
            string goOn = "Y";

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a series of numbers, when you wish to stop entering numbers please enter -99.");
            Console.WriteLine("The smallest and largest values will then be displayed.");
            Console.WriteLine("Remember not to enter -99 unless you want the series to end.");
            do
            {
                while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number))
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter whole numbers only");

                while (number != -99)
                {
                    process(ref number, ref minValue, ref maxValue);

                    while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number))
                        Console.WriteLine("Please enter whole numbers only");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("The smallest value is {0} and the largest value is {1}.", minValue, maxValue);
                Console.WriteLine("Do you want to enter another series of numbers?");
                Console.WriteLine("If so enter y, if you want to end press any other key");
                goOn = Console.ReadLine();
                if (goOn.ToUpper() == "Y")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your set of numbers.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Remember not to enter -99 unless you want the series to end.");
                }

            } while (goOn.ToUpper() == "Y");
        }
        static void process(ref double minValue, ref double maxValue, ref double number)
        {

            if (number > maxValue)
            {
                number = maxValue;
            }
            if (number < minValue)
            {
                number = minValue;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I haven't learned arrays or bubbles or classes yet, but here are the issues:

Probably because of the method of getting the min and max values, if I type in say 3, 22, 7, 15, 1 I will get 15 instead of 22 because the value 22 has been thrown out and replaced by 7.

The minimum value isn't being displayed and is instead showing up as 0

when a non-number is entered, and after the error message is displayed, then more numbers are entered, then the minValue shows up the same as the maxValue.

Comment: Your current method *never* changes `minValue` or `maxValue`. It *only* changes `number`. That seems unlikely to be what you want. (I strongly suspect you shouldn't be passing `number` by reference at all...) Additionally, it's very odd to ask for whole numbers, when you're parsing doubles... so "3.5" is fine, but it's not a whole number...

Comment: I switched it already but the minValue still isn't showing up unless it's less than 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a simple mistake :

```
static void process(ref double minValue, ref double maxValue, ref double number)
    {

        if (number > maxValue)
        {
            maxValue = number;
        }
        if (number < minValue)
        {
            minValue = number;
        }

    }
```

You must affect maxValue and minValue, not number.

Comment: It's still not inputting anything for minValue, is that an issue with the variable passing?

Comment: @Sabotenderizer: Yes, it will. So have you tried thinking about why that is? What's the initial value for `minValue`, and what's the only condition in which it will change?

Comment: Note that `number` doesn't need to be passed by reference - and I'd argue that it *shouldn't* be passed by reference.

Comment: The initial values for maxValue and minValue are bad too. Actually, minValue will update only if number is less than the actual value of minValue : it means only if number is less than 0 (because 0 is the initial value for minValue). You must select a big number as initial value for minValue : Double.MaxValue for instance (so minValue will update if number is less than Double.MaxValue). The problem is the same for maxValue : for the moment, only values greater than 0 will change maxValue. maxValue should be initialized to Double.MinValue.

Comment: It still seems to do it after not setting number to 0.

Comment: @user1773886 how exactly should that change take place?

Comment: `double number = 0, maxValue = Double.MinValue, minValue = Double.MaxValue;`